# count number of days between nextmonth and nextmonth +2days

Tags: mysql

Find the number of days in created field between  COUNT(next month (createddate)

How to do this using mysql query Query need for both datatype date and datetime

EX :

created           Expirydate
2-01-2011         2-02-2011 
3-04-2010         3-02-2011

Result number of days 1

Comment: your question needs clarifying.  Right now you appear to be asking for the difference between April 28th and April 30th, or if run last month, March 28th and March 30th.  And the difference will obviously always be 2 days.

Comment: As @dnagirl says, the number of days between something and something +2 days is likely to always be 2.

Comment: Looks like a homework problem? Have you given this a shot? And wouldn't the number of days between next month and next month +2 days always be 2 days?

Comment: Your example doesn't clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a function TO_DAYS(), which for dates after the year 1582 will give you a day number. Two dates can be converted to day numbers, and these can then be substracted. See the manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days.

MySQL has date and time arithmethic using DATE_ADD() or `date + INTERVAL 2 DAY`. This functionality can be used to find the desired date. See the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

And the difference between a day and that day + INTERVAL 2 DAY is always 2 DAYS, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

You'll use INTERVAL() but you need to be more specific.